# SSIS Email Task

Tags: email, ssis, configuration, environment-variables

I have an SSIS package that has a failure message email task and a success message email task. I have created two variables for each task to signify on which environment it is being run on (test or prod). The variables are as follow:-

EmailFailure_Prod = The package pointing to production (APP_MSR_ImportMemOutcomes)  failed to execute at 11/28/2017

EmailFailure_Test = The package pointing to test (APP_MSR_ImportMemOutcomes)  failed to execute at 11/28/2017

EmailSuccess_Prod = The package pointing to production (APP_MSR_ImportMemOutcomes)  succeeded to execute at 11/28/2017 9:09:26 AM by username on server

EmailSucess_Test = The package pointing to test (APP_MSR_ImportMemOutcomes)  succeeded to execute at 11/28/2017 9:09:26 AM by username on server

I want to configure these variables into the package configuration so that they switch off depending on which environment the package is being run on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 4 variables, you should have only two:  `EmailFailure` and `EmailSuccess`.

Then you put the values of those variables in the .config file, with the Production message in the production .config file, and the Test message on test.

Alternatively, if you are using SSIS 2012+ with the project deployment method, you would make two parameters and populate them in the project in SSISDB.   Same strategy, newer tools.

Comment: Hello @TabAlleman can you show me the steps I am not sure I am following. Thanks.

Comment: The steps depend on the version of SSIS you are using.

Comment: I am using 2012 visual studio.

Comment: This looks like a good tutorial.  You can also google for others:   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1405/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-package-configuration/